# Write discovered bluetooth devices to a text file

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, text-files

I've written a code which should discover bluetooth devices and write it to the text file. But when writing to the text file, only the last found device is written and the rest of it are ignored.

For example my device discovers "abcd", "efgh", & "ijkl" bluetooth devices, and only "ijkl" is written to the text file.

How do I write all the discovered devices to text file?

Below is the code of my Broadcast Receiver

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver bcReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            deviceName = device.getName();

            try{
                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder");
                if(!root.exists()){
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                File deviceFiles = new File(root, "File");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(deviceFiles);
                writer.append(deviceName);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            btArrayAdapter.add(deviceName);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because, you are creating a new file, every time a new device is found. So after saving **abcd** device in the file (say **DeviceFile**), it then searches for the next device, on finding **efgh**, it then creates a file **DeviceFile** which replaces the old one. thus only the last device is saved in the file.

So create the file before starting the scan.

**Edit-**

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver bcReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        File deviceFiles;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                File root = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder");
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                deviceFiles = new File(root, "File");
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                deviceName = device.getName();
                try {
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                            "deviceFiles", true));
                    out.write(deviceName);
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                btArrayAdapter.add(deviceName);
            }
        }
    };
```

Though I havent tested it. Just implemented the logic. Make the relavent adjustments if required.

Comment: Creating file before starting the scan, only writes the first device. Tried placing the pieces of codes in all combinations, in either cases only first or last device is written to file. Any idea how to properly place the file writing code snippet

Comment: If the edited answer doesnt work, then try writing the Array data onto the file. I can see that you are storing device names in ***btArrayAdapter.add(deviceName);***, so why dont you write this array data onto the file.

Comment: Excellent, I had tried same code but without BufferedWriter and quotes("") aren't necessary. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First - Create the file before starting the scan as Sahil has suggested.
Also use the parameter to open the file in append mode-

```
writer = new FileWriter(deviceFiles, true);
writer.write(deviceName);
```

Comment: I can't open the file in append mode, as am writing a new file for each scan